# minimal conductors among elliptic curves with a fixed CM type

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let $K$ be a quadratic imaginary field. To simplify my life, let us assume
that $K$ has class number one.

Consider the following infinite set:

$S_1:=$ $\{$ $E\subseteq\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbf{C})$ is an embedded elliptic curve defined over $\mathcal{O}_K$ with global minimal Weierstrass equation and with CM by $K$
}

Let $S_2=\{N_{K/\mathbf{Q}}(f_E):E\in S_1 \mbox{where $f_E\subseteq\mathcal{O}_K$ is the conductor of $E/\mathcal{O}_K$ }\}$.

Q1: Is it possible to find an explicit expression $C_K$ (where we think of $K$ as a parameter; forget for the moment that there are only 9 such fields), depending only on $K$ (involving for example the discriminant of $K$), such that there exists always an elliptic curve $E\in S_1$ such that $N_{K/\mathbf{Q}}(f_E)\leq C_K$?

Q2: What do we know about the minimal values in the set $S_2$ ?

Comment: There is a CM elliptic curve (over Q) of conductor $p^2$ for $p=7,11,19,43,67,163$, of conductor $256$ for $d=-8$, and $27$ and $32$ for $d=-3,-4$. I don't know if this helps you or not. I think Greenberg or Rohrlich has a "canonical" Grossencharacter (which is not canonical when $h\neq 1$, maybe need $8\not | d$ also) of infinity type (0,1) and the specified level, namely of norm $\frak p$ for $p=7..163$, and $\frak p^2$ for $d=-3$, and $\frak p^3$ for $d=-4$ and $\frak p^5$ for $d=-8$.

Comment: See also the Lemma page 3 of http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01388657

Comment: Thanks for the data. Yes my questions are closely related to asking for a "canonical Grossencharacter" of a quadratic CM field, but from what you say it seems that such an object does not really exist.

Comment: Maybe yes and no for your purposes. I think they all differ by twisting by a class group character, which would preserve the conductor. Rohrlich's paper is http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077314180 I had the conditions wrong, either $d$ is odd, or $8|d$. In the first case there are $h$ choices, in the second case $2h$. He also takes $d<-4$. He says these canonical characters appear in the book of Gross.

Comment: A bit more precisely, an elliptic curve has CM not by $K$ but by some
order in $K$, i.e. a finite-index subring of $O_K$.  Usually that order
must be $O_K$ itself, but there is one more choice for $d=-4$ and $d=-7$,
and two more for $d=-3$.  In all but one of these four extra cases, 
specifying the CM ring does not affect the answer, 
because there's always a minimal-conductor curve 
with endomorphisms by $O_K$ that's isogenous to $E$
(and isogenies preserve the conductor).  But for $d=-3$ there's
an index-2 subring ${\bf Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ of $O_K$ whose minimal
conductor is not $27$ but $36$.